Getting Access denied error while using aws cli for enabling MFA delete on S3 bucket

Created user and that user having administrator permission and as well S3 bucket full access.
Created S3 bucket with default setting.
Trying to enable MFA delete via AWS CLI:

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket testing-mfa-delete --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:mfa/Admin_App" --profile deletemfa

but getting access denied error:

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: Access Denied

Tried but getting error analyzed and found root account had must had right to do. Even though I am also administrator for that tenant but unable to do it.

Please show the exact command you used and the exact error message.

@JohnRotenstein, please find my command,
** aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket testing-mfa-delete --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::271491774336:mfa/Admin_App" --profile deletemfa**

What is the exact error message?

@JohnRotenstein, the error message is "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: Access Denied"

Log into the root user. Generate access key, secret key for that user. Try the below command, it will work.
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket elbs --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::user 348987"

Based on Turn on MFA delete for Amazon S3 bucket | AWS re:Post, it appears that you need to provide the 6-digit number shown on your device or in your app:

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket mybucketname --versioning-configuration MFADelete=Enabled,Status=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::1XXXXXXX6789:mfa/root-account-mfa-device 123789" --profile deletemfa

Note the inclusion of the example code 123789 from the MFA device.
The document also says that it needs to be done from the root user of your AWS Account. This login typically requires an email address as a login. This suggests that using an IAM User is not sufficient, even if they have Administrator permissions.

Thanks for your update, just a clarification in below document they stated, The bucket owner, the AWS account that created the bucket (root account), and all authorized users can enable versioning. However, only the bucket owner (root account) can enable MFA delete.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html
As my understanding, the aws account, if i am able to create a bucket. I am the owner of that bucket.. right?If am wrong, please correct me on this?

Users do not 'own' buckets. Only the AWS Account owns buckets. I therefore read that document as saying you need to use "root account" credentials with MFA to activate MFA Delete.

Okay thanks for your update. Let me check it

After trying the command with root user of that tenant account, its working. Thanks
